# Razorpay success screen in flutter disappear instantly

Tags: flutter, razorpay, flutter-razorpay

I am implementing Razorpay in a flutter mobile application. Everything works fine till I tap the success button on the Razorpay bank gateway screen[image]

But on tapping the success button, a payment success page appears automatically and disappears instantly and the user is returned to the page with the payment button. How can I redirect users to my app's payment success screen to display transaction details instead of showing Razorpay's success screen for an instant and returning to the screen with the payment button?